# Уведомление о изменении файла в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, ide, ftp

помогите решить проблему которая появилась после обновления phpstorm (лицензия). Работаю через FTP, и при сохранении и загрузке изменений в файле на сервер каждый раз начало всплывать уведомление (первый скриншот) что файл был изменен на сервере, хотя раньше такого не было.
Переустановка и очистка кеша не помогла. Скриншоты уведомления и настроек прилагаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пробовали настройку `Warn when uploading over newer file` переключить в `No`?

Comment: Спасибо большое! На текущий момент помогло, но раньше, до обновления такой проблемы при условиях что в скриншоте не было.

Comment: Написал в ответ, чтобы закрыть тему, отметьте вопрос решенным. Может они (JetBrains) этот момент как-то переделали в последних обновлениях. Я лично как-то всегда и No  ставил и галочку снимал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настройку `Warn when uploading over newer file` переключить в `No`